# Flash Stock ROM (Mediatek) over Fastboot

Tags: rom-flashing, fastboot, stock-rom

I want to flash a stock ROM for my device with MTK6572 CPU which is meant to be flashed through SP Flash tool (scatter-based ROM) but I want to flash it through Fastboot. So can I do it by flashing all the images one by one?

```
fastboot flash boot boot.img
fastboot flash cache cache.img
fastboot flash recovery cwm.img
fastboot flash system system.img
fastboot flash data userdata.img
fastboot reboot
```

Is this method safe for my device? If yes, do I need my bootloader to be unlocked for this? And how will the rest of the images be flashed? (secro.img, ramdisk.img, ramdisk-recovery.img, EBR1, MBR, logo.bin, preloader.bin)

Answer (score 3):

If your phone's bootloader is locked then you definitely need to unlock it before performing those operations or non of them will succeed (the bootloader throws an error of some sort like "FAILED (remote: Command not allowed)"

I ran this command on a phone with locked bootloader

```
C:\AGUSTINO_ROOT\2014-08-02.21.07.25>fastboot flash recovery recovery.img

target reported max download size of 301989888 bytes

sending 'recovery' (6144 KB)...

OKAY [  0.265s]

writing 'recovery'...

FAILED (remote: Command not allowed)

finished. total time: 0.281s
```

According to my experience, any partition recognized by the bootloader can be flashed using fastboot, to get list of known partition run

```
fastboot getvar all
```

This is my brief sample output:

```
C:\Users\kjhn>fastboot getvar all

(bootloader)    partition-size:logo: 300000

(bootloader)    partition-type:logo: raw data

(bootloader)    partition-type:userdata: ext4

(bootloader)    partition-type:cache: ext4

(bootloader)    partition-size:system: 28a00000

(bootloader)    partition-type:system: ext4


(bootloader)    partition-type:ebr1: raw data

(bootloader)    partition-type:mbr: raw data

(bootloader)    partition-type:preloader: raw data


(bootloader)    version: 0.5

all: Done!!

finished. total time: 0.031s
```

Note the partitions names logo, mbr, ebr1 etc..

This method is as safe as the files you are trying to flash, make sure the ROM is compatible with your device before attempting this.

I also advise you not to temper with the preloader unless you are absolutely certain as it results into unrecoverable brick