# Which files do I need to flash with fastboot to get a stock device state?

Tags: rom-flashing, fastboot, factory-image, mediatek

I have downloaded the stock ROM for my Mediatek (MT6580) device. Extracting the files leads me to a couple of `*.img` files and SP Flash Tool. I am currently on a Linux distro and have `adb` and `fastboot` packages installed, and am not able to use the SP Flash Tool. I was wondering which files do I need to flash to get a factory version of the phone.

`fastboot getvar all` shows these outputs

```
(bootloader)    max-download-size: 0x8000000
(bootloader)    partition-size:userdata: 32000000
(bootloader)    partition-type:userdata: ext4
(bootloader)    partition-size:cache: 10000000
(bootloader)    partition-type:cache: ext4
(bootloader)    partition-size:system: 5d000000
(bootloader)    partition-type:system: ext4
(bootloader)    partition-size:metadata: 2560000
(bootloader)    partition-type:metadata: raw data
(bootloader)    partition-size:nvdata: 2000000
(bootloader)    partition-type:nvdata: ext4
(bootloader)    partition-size:tee2: 500000
(bootloader)    partition-type:tee2: raw data
(bootloader)    partition-size:tee1: 500000
(bootloader)    partition-type:tee1: raw data
(bootloader)    partition-size:frp: 100000
(bootloader)    partition-type:frp: raw data
(bootloader)    partition-size:expdb: a00000
(bootloader)    partition-type:expdb: raw data
(bootloader)    partition-size:logo: 800000
(bootloader)    partition-type:logo: raw data
(bootloader)    partition-size:para: 80000
(bootloader)    partition-type:para: raw data
(bootloader)    partition-size:keystore: 800000
(bootloader)    partition-type:keystore: raw data
(bootloader)    partition-size:secro: 600000
(bootloader)    partition-type:secro: raw data
(bootloader)    partition-size:oemkeystore: 200000
(bootloader)    partition-type:oemkeystore: raw data
(bootloader)    partition-size:recovery: 1000000
(bootloader)    partition-type:recovery: raw data
(bootloader)    partition-size:boot: 1000000
(bootloader)    partition-type:boot: raw data
(bootloader)    partition-size:lk: 60000
(bootloader)    partition-type:lk: raw data
(bootloader)    partition-size:seccfg: 40000
(bootloader)    partition-type:seccfg: raw data
(bootloader)    partition-size:protect2: a00000
(bootloader)    partition-type:protect2: ext4
(bootloader)    partition-size:protect1: a00000
(bootloader)    partition-type:protect1: ext4
(bootloader)    partition-size:nvram: 500000
(bootloader)    partition-type:nvram: raw data
(bootloader)    partition-size:proinfo: 300000
(bootloader)    partition-type:proinfo: raw data
(bootloader)    partition-size:preloader: 40000
(bootloader)    partition-type:preloader: raw data
(bootloader)    off-mode-charge: 1
(bootloader)    warranty: no
(bootloader)    unlocked: yes
(bootloader)    secure: no
(bootloader)    kernel: lk
(bootloader)    product: RS615
(bootloader)    version: 0.5
all: Done!!
finished. total time: 0.012s
```

Comment: What makes it impossible for you to use the SP Flashtool? I remember it works fine on Linux (if you have the linux variant of it), having used it with a MTK device several years ago. AFAIR I've followed [this guide](https://forum.xda-developers.com/general/rooting-roms/tutorial-how-to-setup-spflashtoollinux-t3160802) back then.

Comment: Running this distro using a live usb thumb drive. My hard disk drive is busted unfortunately. I have downloaded all the adb and fastboot packages properly on this distro, and seems to be working fine. Are there ways to do it without the flash tools?

Comment: Im running the distro on my RAM and running from a live USB drive, since hdd is busted. I was able to flash boot.img and recovery.img earlier.

Comment: okay I also found this https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/125599/flash-stock-rom-mediatek-over-fastboot answer here. Dont know how to apprehend it properly. Perhaps a better guide would be appreciated. Athough my question and the other one mentioned here are of the same type but without an acceptable answer.

Comment: some partitions are important and must not erased like *preloader secro seccfg nvdata nvram lk logo* and some of them are device specific therefore not included in downloaded stock ROM https://blog.csdn.net/zhangbijun1230/article/details/81092381

Comment: Thanks. A couple hours back I tried doing `fastboot flash userdata userdata.img` and it said that filesystem limit reached or something like that or filesystem limit exceeded. The userdata file was ~ 28 mb. Wish there was a way to get around that. If userdata can't be flashed, means system can't be flashed as well. I swear I have the worst luck of all. Checkmate on all sides. Dang it.

Comment: have you tried flashing system? flashing userdata is not important (it's wiped anyway on factory reset) you can just *fastboot format:ext4 userdata*